# How to make compound styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I would like to make some compound `style` values for example: `height:100%-10px;`

Is there some way to do this with `CSS`?

Or do you have to use `JavaScript`?

If so can you post your suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
height: calc(100% - 10px);
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/ryVYb/)

> w3.org [**8.1. Mathematical Expressions: ‘calc()’**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)
>
> The calc() function allows mathematical expressions with addition (‘+’), subtraction (‘-’), multiplication (‘*’), and division (‘/’) to be used as component values. The ‘calc()’ expression represents the result of the mathematical calculation it contains, using standard operator precedence rules. It can be used wherever , , , , , or  values are allowed. Components of a ‘calc()’ expression can be literal values, ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ expressions, or  values that resolve to one of the preceding types.